# When doing GET request to localhost:121/logout I get "accounts.views.logout didn't return an HttpResponse object". Is this an issue?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls, django-authentication

When I go to localhost:121/logout I get The view accounts.views.logout didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Should I modify my code, to deal with this, or is this not an issue? My logout is working fine. Do I have to list logout in my urls.py?

views.py

```
def logout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        auth.logout(request)
        return redirect('login')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('', views.login, name='login'),
]
```

profile.html

```
<ul>
<li>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:{document.getElementById('logout').submit()}">Logout</a>
 </li>
 <form id="logout" action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <input type="hidden">
</form>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you want your application to do. What do you want to happen when you navigate to `/logout`? If you want to provide your users with a way of logging out just by navigating there, then you can just deal with the GET and POST requests together. (As suggested by @Beste) e.g:

```
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('login')
```

This has the additional advantage that you can logout from anywhere on the site just by using a hyperlink to this URL.

If you don't want this to happen, I would suggest raising a 405 (method not allowed), e.g:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def logout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        auth.logout(request)
        return redirect('login')
    return HttpResponse(status_code=405)
```

And yes, whatever you do you will need to list it in your `urls.py` somewhere. Or you could even use a `HttpResponseNotAllowed` (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses))

Comment: If I put GET and POST together, is there any point to having a POST request as a part of my profile.html, or should I just switch it to GET <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>

Comment: If it's part of a form, or you want to use AJAX, then you might have reason to use a POST, but I can't see any reason why you should have to do this with a POST, and a link as you suggest should work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

GET and POST requests can be redirected the login page. The logout method is also suitable for logged out users.

```
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('login')
```